# in jQuery what is the difference between $.myFunction and $.fn.myFunction?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm delving into writing plugins for jQuery and I'm trying to understand the distinction between $.f and $.fn.f

I've seen pluggin authors use both, or sometimes assign $.f = $.fn.f

Can someone explain this to me, reasoning, benefits, etc?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the jQuery source code will clear things up. By the way, `jQuery` and `$` refer to the same object, and this is how the jQuery object is defined:

```
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
}
```

`jQuery` is a function and in Javascript, a function is also an object of the type `Function`. So `jQuery.f` or `$.f` attaches `f` to the jQuery `Function` object, or call it the jQuery class if you will.

if you look at jQuery's source, you'll see that `jQuery.prototype` has been assigned to `jQuery.fn`

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype
```

So, whenever you attach a method (or property) to `jQuery.fn`, as in `jQuery.fn.f = ..`, or `$.fn.f = ..`, or `jQuery.prototype.f = ..`, or `$.prototype.f = ..`, that method will be available to all instances of this jQuery class (again, there are no classes in Javascript, but it may help in understanding).

Whenever you invoke the `jQuery()` function, as in `jQuery("#someID")`, a new jQuery instance is created on this line:

```
return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
```

and this instance has all the methods we attached to the prototype, but not the methods that were attached directly to the `Function` object.

You will get an exception if you try calling a function that wasn't defined at the right place.

```
$.doNothing = function() {
    // oh noez, i do nuttin
}

// does exactly as advertised, nothing    
$.doNothing();

var jQueryEnhancedObjectOnSteroids = $("body");
// Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'doNothing'
jQueryEnhancedObjectOnSteroids.doNothing();
```

---

Oh, and finally to cut a long thread short and to answer your question - doing `$.f = $.fn.f` allows you to use the function as a plugin or a utility method (in jquery lingo).

Answer (score 4):

The `$.f` is a utility function whereas `$.fn.f` is a jQuery plugin / method.

A utility function is basically a function within the jQuery namespace that is useful for performing some operation, for example, `$.isArray(obj)` checks if an object `obj` is an array. It is useful to put functions in the jQuery namespace if you'll use them often and also to avoid global namespace pollution.

jQuery methods on the other hand operate on jQuery objects/wrapped sets. For example, `$(document.body).append('<p>Hello</p>');` will append a paragraph containing Hello to the body element of the document. `$.fn` is a shorthand for `$.prototype` in later versions of jQuery (it wasn't always in earlier versions of the library). You would use this when writing your own plugins.

Comment: So what is the benefit of $.f = $.fn.f ?

Comment: what do you mean, what is the benefit? They serve different purposes. Can you say where you've seen plugin authors using `$.f = $.fn.f`?

Comment: SimpleModal doesn't assign `$.f = $.fn.f` - it has a utility function for creating a modal `$.modal()` and a jQuery chainable mthod `$(document).modal()` that creates a modal. Both methods call a function `$.modal.impl.init()` to create the modal, but a utility function is not assigned a jQuery plugin function in the source code.

Answer (score 4):

The `$.fn.f` is simply a shortcut to `jQuery.prototype`

By using the `fn`, you can add plugin methods without using the extend method:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function(opts) { ... }
```